# combine two array without foreach

Tags: php

I am making a mailing system, and my input is array of arrays, i need to combine them to one, i already aggregated based on the email.
input example:

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(15) {
["enabled"]=>
string(1) "1"
["file_size_bytes"]=>
string(6) "200122"
["email"]=>
string(21) "jon@gmail.com"
["content"]=>
string(34) "{"Notice":827,"co":3241,"Co":1555}"
}
[1]=>
array(15) {
["enabled"]=>
string(1) "1"
["file_size_bytes"]=>
string(6) "592024"
["email"]=>
string(21) "jon@gmail.com"
["content"]=>
string(97) "{"Co":388,"co":5564,"xml":2982,"CO":6,"Warning":1957,"warning":42,"Notice":13,"cO":9,"Connect":6}"
}
}
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(15) {
["enabled"]=>
string(1) "1"
["file_size_bytes"]=>
string(5) "19116"
["email"]=>
string(22) "kelly@gmail.com"
["content"]=>
string(8) "{"co":1}"
}
}
```

input array to the mail function should look like:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(15) {
["enabled"]=>
string(1) "1"
["file_size_bytes"]=>
string(6) "200122"
["email"]=>
string(21) "jon@gmail.com"
["content"]=>
string(34) "{"Notice":827,"co":3241,"Co":1555}"

["enabled"]=>
string(1) "1"
["file_size_bytes"]=>
string(6) "592024"
["email"]=>
string(21) "jon@gmail.com"
["content"]=>
string(97) "      {"Co":388,"co":5564,"xml":2982,"CO":6,"Warning":1957,"warning":42,"Notice":13,"cO":9,"Conne    ct":6}"
}
}
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(15) {
["enabled"]=>
string(1) "1"
["file_size_bytes"]=>
string(5) "19116"
["email"]=>
string(22) "kelly@gmail.com"
["content"]=>
string(8) "{"co":1}"
}
}
```

its basically spouse to combine the two arrays that are in the same array.
how can i do that? thanks :)

Comment: Would be more readable if you post the `<pre>` formatted `print_r()` output of the arrays instead.

Comment: you right , just a sec

Answer (score 1):

The required outcome is not possible since you have duplicate keys in the array which won't be possible in PHP.

e.g.

```
["content"] => string(34) "{"Notice":827,"co":3241,"Co":1555}"
```

will be replaced by

```
["content"] => string(97) "{"Co":388,"co":5564,"xml":2982,"CO":6,"Warning":1957,"warning":42,"Notice":13,"cO":9,"Connect":6}"
```

Comment: Do you want to rename the duplicate keys? Like: content1, content2, etc
OR
turn the value into a sub array content=>array(content1, content2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply using the `array_merge` function.

In their answer, Maarten suggests this is not possible because duplicate keys would be overwritten. However this only occurs when the keys aren't numeric. In your example above the keys of the first array are 0 and 1 and the second just 0. All numeric.

So all you need to do is:

```
array_merge($array1,$array2);
```